# How can i fix this javascript news horizontal ticker?

Tags: javascript, css

There is a problem in my code and can't seem to find it. My news ticker won't scroll. Can anyone help me out to fix it.

I don't want to use html seperate. I just want a complete javascript code.

```
var width = $('.ticker-text').width(),
  containerwidth = $('.ticker-container').width(),
  left = containerwidth;
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  function tick() {
    if (--left < -width) {
      left = containerwidth;
    }
    $(".ticker-text").css("margin-left", left + "px");
    setTimeout(tick, 16);
  } {
    var $markup = $('<div id="clientip"><div class = "ticker-container><div class = "ticker-text">start text text text text</div></div></div>');
    $markup.insertAfter('#header-userinfo');
  }
  tick();
});
```

CSS code:

```
#clientip {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.ticker-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.9%;
    border: 1px solid;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ticker-text {
    height: 150%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the width of `.ticker-text` and `.ticker-container` at the beginning of your script, but insert them after that. If you reorganize the code a little it should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    // insertAfter returns the jQuery object.
    var $markup = $('<div id="clientip"><div class = "ticker-container><div class = "ticker-text">start text text text text</div></div></div>').insertAfter('#header-userinfo'),
        $tickerText = $(".ticker-text"),
        width = $tickerText.width(),
        containerwidth = $('.ticker-container').width(),
        left = containerwidth;

    function tick() {
        if(--left < -width){
            left = containerwidth;
        }
        $tickerText.css("margin-left", left + "px");
        setTimeout(tick, 16);
    }

    tick();
});
```

That's untested. I also created a variable for the ticker text dom object, to prevent querying the dom on each frame.

If you don't need anything special, maybe you can use `<marquee>` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee))

Comment: Also the bar scrolls and not the text.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are calculating the dimensions of your `.ticker-container` element before it exists!

So move the `width` variables down *underneath* the `insertAfter()`.

You also have a couple of typos in the generated html (`class="ticker-container` missing a quote, extra space between attributes).

This should work better:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  function tick() {
    if (--left < -width) {
      left = containerwidth;
    }
    console.log(containerwidth);
    $(".ticker-text").css("margin-left", left + "px");
    setTimeout(tick, 16);
  }

  var $markup = $('<div id="clientip"><div class="ticker-container"><div class="ticker-text">start text text text text</div></div></div>');

  $markup.insertAfter('#header-userinfo');

  // calculate dimensions here now the elements exist!
  var width = $('.ticker-text').width(),
    containerwidth = $('.ticker-container').width(),
    left = containerwidth;

  tick();
});
```

```css
#clientip {
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.ticker-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.9%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ticker-text {
    height: 150%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header-userinfo"></div>
```

Comment: The text needs to scroll not the frame. With your script the frame is scrolling. the frame bar must be static and the text needs to scroll inside of it.

Comment: remove the `float:left` or set a fixed `width` then - updated with fixed width

Comment: Nope bar is still scrolling.